# PyInstaller attaches 2 icons to exe

Tags: icons, pyinstaller

I use PyInstaller to get a single file executable from my python script.
as seen in this thread : [Pyinstaller setting icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29291113/pyinstaller-setting-icon) 
it is not that complicated to add a icon to the .exe file.

Except that it adds 2 icons :
* when I show "Medium icons" (or bigger) in the windows explorer, then I see the standard PyInstaller icon
* when I show "small icons" (or smaller, like in "details view") then I get the icon I specified.

With a "iconviewer" I can see that the default icon is mine, but the PyInstaller icon has ID=1

is there a method to get avoid this second (ID=1) icon ?

My icon is already 256x256 big...
According to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3244679/4316500 Windows 7 does not need bigger icons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem solve itself alone...
The day (and a reboot) after my long time search on that problem, the icon was OK.
Perhaps the Windows cache for icons where preventing me to see the right icon.

Still not clear because I'm also sure that my iconviewer saw 2 different icons. Now, I have twice the same (and wanted) icon. It's twice too much, but nobody sees it.