# PyInstaller EXE Changes Back To Original Icon

Tags: python, icons, pyinstaller, .ico

I have created a standalone `.exe` file with PyInstaller using this command: `pyinstaller --onefile -i "icon0.ico" test.py -w`. When I open the `dist` folder the `exe` gets put into it shows the icon I used but the moment I copy or move it from that folder the icon disappears and it returns back to the stock PyInstaller icon.

Oddly enough if I rename the file the icon stays like it is supposed to, but I can't use this as a solution since I have other files that depend on my `exe` being a specific filename. I used [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/) to view the icon contents, I completely replaced the stock icon with my icon but after saving it nothing changed, still the same old stock PyInstaller icon. Yes, my `.ico` file had all the different 256x256, 128x128, 64x64, 48x48, 32x32 and 16x16 sizes.

What can I do to fix this?

PyInstaller version: 3.4

Python version: 3.7.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually use:

```shell
pyinstaller --onefile -w --icon=*icon name*.ico test.py
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```shell
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --name=filename --icon=icon.ico script.py
```

Works well, but the `.ico` file must be in the same directory as the `.exe` file. Any other options work as well, but haven't tried removing `--onefile`.

Note: `--name` required. I am not certain why.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this issue, it might apply to your case too. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29291113/12806969)for the related question.

I had same issue, I tried both putting `pyinstaller ... --icon=icon/path/icon.ico ... main.py` and editing `pyinstaller.spec` file,

```
exe = EXE(pyz,
          ...
          console=False , icon='C:\\icon\\path\\icon.ico')
```

**But none of these solutions  seems to work.**
So, as mentioned on the link above, **changing/renaming the directory /dist/** or **renaming** the .exe file immidiately changes the icon.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming python 3.10, you need to make the icon known within the pyInstaller environment. My batch file is:

```
<full_path>\pyinstaller -wF --onefile --add-binary myicon.ico;. --icon myicon.ico app.py 2> build_log.txt
```

and in the python file app.py add:

```
import os, sys
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    # If the application is run as a bundle, the PyInstaller bootloader
    # extends the sys module by a flag frozen=True and sets the app 
    # path into variable _MEIPASS'.
    application_path = sys._MEIPASS
else:
    application_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

then refer to the icon with:

```
os.path.join(application_path,'myicon.ico')
```