# Python pyinstaller onefile executable problem with image

Tags: python, image, icons, exe, pyinstaller

I have created an .exe with some tabs, plots, input and outputs.
It compiles perfectly in pycharm with pyinstaller and the command: `pyinstaller -w -F -file_name.py` and it works in every windows computer.

The problem started when I tried to insert an image in the program and add an icon through the pyinstaller command `-i \path`.
In both cases the executable doesn't run and returns an error.

I think the problem could be in the way I refer to the path of the image and icon file; is there a proper way to do it?

Sorry if the question may sound basic but I just started programming and except from some matlab knowledge this is completely new for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29291113/pyinstaller-setting-icon

Comment: Can you show the code where you add the image? You may be forgetting to retain a reference to the image.