# Pyinstaller executable doesn't work if I move the dependency

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe

So I created an exe file using pyinstaller and gave it an icon as well using -i my_icon.ico and the executable works well but if I delete my_icon.ico or move it from it's current directory, it stops working?? Any solution to this so that the executable will work even without the dependency

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pyinstaller setting icons don't change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29291113/pyinstaller-setting-icons-dont-change)

Comment: I suggest you improve your question, add some examples, some code and make it more clear and add your source code, Have a look here => [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)